# kubectl port-forward to another endpoint

Tags: kubernetes, portforwarding, tunnel

Is there a corresponding command with `kubectl` to:

```
ssh -L8888:rds.aws.com:5432 example.com
```

`kubectl` has `port-forward` you can also specify `--address` but that strictly requires an IP address.

Comment: "kubectl port-forward" is intended to forward local ports ( optionally only from "--address" local IP address ) to a pod port in k8s cluster. It doesn't forward ports to any destination, just inside k8s cluster.

Answer (score 17):

The [older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61271752) is valid.
Still, a workaround would be to use something like
https://hub.docker.com/r/marcnuri/port-forward

`kubectl run --env REMOTE_HOST=your.service.com --env REMOTE_PORT=8080 --env LOCAL_PORT=8080 --port 8080 --image marcnuri/port-forward test-port-forward`

Run it on the cluster and then port forward to it.

`kubectl port-forward test-port-forward 8080:8080`

Comment: But the kubectl has to run into the remote host or local?

Answer (score 7):

Short answer, No.

> In  [OpenSSH](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/openssh/), local port forwarding is configured using the  `-L`  option:
>
> ```
>    ssh -L 80:intra.example.com:80 gw.example.com
> ```
>
> This example opens a connection to the  `gw.example.com`  jump server, and forwards any connection to port 80 on the local machine to port 80 on  `intra.example.com`.
>
> By default, anyone (even on different machines) can connect to the specified port on the SSH client machine. However, this can be restricted to programs on the same host by supplying a  *bind address*:
>
> ```
>    ssh -L 127.0.0.1:80:intra.example.com:80 gw.example.com
> ```

You can read the docs [here](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example).

The `port-forward` in Kubernetes works only within the cluster, you can forward traffic that will hit specified port to `Deployment` or `Service` or a `Pod`

```
kubectl port-forward TYPE/NAME [options] [LOCAL_PORT:]REMOTE_PORT [...[LOCAL_PORT_N:]REMOTE_PORT_N]
```

`--address` flag is to specify what to listen on `0.0.0.0` means everything `localhost` is as name and you can set an IP on which it can be listening on.
Documentation is available [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#port-forward), you can also read [Use Port Forwarding to Access Applications in a Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/).

Answer (score 6):

One workaround you can use if you have an SSH server somewhere on the Internet is to SSH to your server from your pod, port-forwarding in reverse:

```
# Suppose a web console is being served at 
# http://my-service-8f6717ab-e.default:8888/
# inside your cluster:

kubectl exec -it my-job-f523b248-7htj6 -- ssh -R8888:my-service-8f6717ab-e.default:8888 user@34.23.1.2
```

Then you can connect to the service inside Kubernetes from outside of it. If the SSH server is not local to you, you can SSH to it from your local machine with a normal port forward:

```
me@my-macbook-pro:$ ssh -L8888:localhost:8888 user@34.23.1.2
```

Then point your browser to http://localhost:8888/

Comment: I did not try, but a good idea